# soap parsing wsdl error: Unexpected element: TAG_END

Tags: wsdl, soapui

I have an error importing a WSDL definition from an ASP.NET version 4 Visual Studio 2010 Express project, into SOAPUI 4.5.1

URL would be like

```
http://localhost:7929/ws/AX.asmx?WSDL
```

Error generated

```
Error loading [http://localhost:7929/ws/AX.asmx?WSDL]: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException:
org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: Unexpected element: TAG_END
```

Error trace:

```
com.eviware.soapui.impl.support.definition.support.InvalidDefinitionException
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.wsdl.WsdlLoader.loadXmlObject(WsdlLoader.java:138)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.xsd.SchemaUtils.getDefinitionParts(SchemaUtils.java:535)
...
```

Any suggestions most welcome!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I had the same issue with Soap UI 5.2.0

The solution for me was to turn off the proxy (as suggested by @user518066)

[image]

Comment: It worked! It'd be nice for someone to edit the answer and include a quick explanation about why was that a problem.

Comment: @daniloquio, sorry, but I don't know the explanation of why it works.

Comment: It's three years later, and I'm confident that both this explanation and the volume of upvotes on the @user518066 comment are indicative of a correct (or at least more likey) answer. Thanks Alin - maybe you deserve some kind of badge.

Comment: Still here with version 5.2.1. Thanks!

Comment: This solution works perfectly on version 5.4.0. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

The issue is that soapui doesn't know where to find the schema file.
If your wsdl is deployed to a server, it will return a url of the xsd file to include and soapui will be able to find it....

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Marijke.  
I have no idea how to change the location/url of the xsd file (I thought the entities were defined in a namespace within the same wsdl file), but I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: I get a similar issue. When I run with soapui version 4.5.2 it works. However with version 5.0.0, I get this error.

Comment: I got it to work with soapui version 5.0.0. Changed proxy setting to none.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, after several hours I found that the problem was about IPv6.

When I go to service URL I can see and validate the wsdl file. There was no problem at all.

```
http://localhost/SoapServer.php?wsdl
```

But when I add this URL to SoapUI it gives error `Unexpected element: TAG_END`.
I found the reason by using cURL, `curl http://localhost/SoapServer.php?wsdl` returns 404!!

So realized that my Apache listens both IPv4 and IPv6, browser goes to IPv6 and gets the wsdl but cURL and SoapUI goes to IPv4 and get 404 error.

I disabled IPv6 on my Apache by removing the line `Listen [::0]:80` in `httpd.conf` file, this solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the service is running?
When debugging solutions with several WCF projects, there are times in which we could think that we are running the project we are working into and it turns not be that case.
If you face an Error 404 when enter the svc url into a browser, then this could be the cause of the problem.
In that scenario, SOAP UI will fail when trying to add or create a new WSDL endpoint.
So, make sure that your solution starts running from the project where the target svc is located.