# org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: Unexpected element: TAG_EN

Tags: java, apache, wsdl, soapui

I tried to connect with wsdl  URL in soap UI but it gives following error
 below I am mentioning  URL and error respectively

```
http://192.168.0.117:4911/ADInterface/services/ModelADService?wsdl
```

Error

```
Error loading [http://192.168.0.117:4911/ADInterface/services/ModelADService?wsdl]: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: Unexpected element: TAG_END
```

Comment: try to open wsdl file in browser check if it is valid. Looks like you have extra `>` element

Comment: I think that it's not the *wsdl* itself, instead it's probably the referenced *xsd* for the request and response, take a look on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981902/soap-parsing-wsdl-error-unexpected-element-tag-end). Anyway if you include or reference your *wsdl* we can take a more deep look on it `:)`

Comment: I tried by changing proxy set to none but still it giving same error

Comment: @Lina The real problem is probably related with the thing that from your machine the necessary schemas are not reachable (so the proxy it's only a solution if in your environment it affects to the download). Check that you can really download the imported schemas of your *wsdl*.

Comment: Please tell me where I check the wsdl file. I am trying to open same URL in browser but its not opening. how can I resolve this issue

Comment: @Lina If you can not download the *wsdl* in the browser using the url... then the same problem it's happening in *SOAPUI*. Make sure that the endpoint it's reachable from your machine before trying to import the *wsdl* in *SOAPUI*. The problem it's surely that *SOAPUI* can not download the *wsdl*.

Comment: How can I find the issue, why is it not opening in browser